# Edit data in joined tables (mysql) in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Anybody knows if it possible to edit data in PHPMyAdmin, in table, made by joining two (mysql) tables like this:

```
SELECT * , pl.name
FROM product p
JOIN product_language pl ON p.product_id = pl.product_id
AND pl.lang_id =4
ORDER BY p.product_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

If I select only one table, I can edit data in it no problem, but when I join two, I cannot.
Would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't edit joined tables, because there's no way for it to know what you're actually editing. For instance, you could have done "select concat(pl.id,'_',p.product_id)". Since phpmyadmin has no way of predicting what you might be showing, it can't let you edit it; it has no way to map that back to a primary key to know how to modify the original data.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking similarly, asked just in case.

Comment: I disagree. For a very simple query which extract pure fields with a single id from a table joined whit another one (e.g. `SELECT A.id, A.col1, A.col2, A.code, B.codeUser FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN table2 B ON A.code = B.codeUser`), it should know at which table every field belong. It hasn't this feature only because it isn't developed yet.

Comment: Fair enough. Can’t was a strong word, and I meant it in the sense that phpmyadmin can’t, and I gave why the developers didn’t. I should have said “doesn’t”.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer omits the fact that it is quite possible to update joined tables in MySQL if you [create an updatable view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-updatability.html).  Whether phpMyAdmin will allow you to edit them might be a different story, but it *should*, since updatable views have been implemented since MySQL 5.0.  Such views certainly can be created and can be edited with `UPDATE` statements.  A view should behave like any other table in this case.

Comment: I was answering the question asked. Whether phpmyadmin should or shouhldn't is irrelevant. It can't. Still, I like the reference.

Comment: @juacala It CAN. The only limit is what developers WANT to develop.

Comment: The question had nothing to do with views. It had to do to with whether phpmyadmin can edit a join query. I stand by my answer. What are people suggesting? Phpmyadmin creates an updatable view every time a query is run? and destroys it when? If it doesn’t create a view, a developer would have to recreate the updatable view machinery in PHP… sounds wrong.  Fine, create an updatable view, but it’s not a join query.

Comment: Sorry for the defensive tone. Updatable views are great, and give the functionality requested. Also @user2342558, fair enough.